# The data is overwritten in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that keeps records only for 3 months then overwrite these data.
I want to keep all the data so I made a merge replication between this database and another database but the data is still overwritten in both databases (publisher and distributor)

What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: You'll obviously need to change the process that overwrites 3 months data! If you explain what that is then we can take a guess. If you can't change that then you need to do some more manual replication (i.e. via SSIS). Since you are trying replication, is it an option to keep one table being overwritten and keep another table with the entire history? Does your table have a key that can be used to uniquely identify rows?

Comment: this database is connected to an application which contains a code to delete any records in the database for more than 90 days. the application is not supported any more for our company so we can't change the code.I tried merge replication but is acts like a transaction one and don't no why. the table contains a unique ID for each row

Comment: merge replication will add and delete so that the tables remain identical.It won't keep a history for you. Are the databases on the same SQL Server or a different SQL Server? If they are on the same SQL Server and you have a key you can use to identify rows, you can run one or two sql statements to get what you want. Please clarify that and I will post an answer

Comment: yes they are in the same SQL server

Comment: I tried the following query :
 INSERT INTO DB2..T1
SELECT * FROM DB1..T1
WHERE DB2..T1.ID != DB1..T1.ID  

but i got this error :   The multi-part identifier "DB2..T1.ID" could not be bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
INSERT INTO DB2..T1 (column1,column2,column3)
SELECT column1,column2,column3
FROM DB1..T1 As Src
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM DB2..T1 As Tgt
   WHERE Tgt.ID = Src.ID
   )
```

Comment: Thank you Nick for your great support

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following query and it works !

insert into DB2..T1
select * from DB1 ..T1
where DB1 ..T1.ID not in ( select ID from DB2..T1)